# What is the technique used to prove that a sequence does exist and is unique?

Tags: sequences-and-series, contest-math

Here is a question about sequences from the British Mathematical Olympiad.

> Show that there is a unique sequence of positive integers ($a_n$) satisfying the following conditions: $$a_1=1, a_2=2, a_4=12$$ $$ a_{n+1}a_{n-1} = a_{n}^2\pm1$$ for $n=2, 3, 4, ...$

I managed to get the first few terms to be $1, 2, 5, 12, 29, 70, 169$, which are the Pell numbers, characterised by the recurrence relation $a_{n} = 2a_{n-1} + a_{n-2}$, but can't seem to go from there.

In general, I was wondering if anyone had any advice of proving that a particular sequence is indeed unique.

Comment: [Possible duplicate](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/702952/show-that-there-is-a-unique-sequence-of-positive-integers-a-n-satisfying-a?rq=1).

Comment: I think the second answer is a bit sketchy + I am asking about a more general technique as well

Comment: It's good that you point that out. Note that I didn't even vote to close, I was putting the fact that the problem at hand has been asked before out there .

Comment: No worries mate - thanks for pointing that out though