$a_n = \frac{a_{n-1}^2+ 2}{a_{n-2}}$ produces only integers

If a sequence ($a_n$) is defined so that $a_1 = a_2 = 1$ and for $n ≥ 3$, $$a_n = \frac{a_{n-1}^2+ 2}{a_{n-2}}.$$
Show that all $a_i$ are integers.

How do I approach this problem?
I took the first few terms of this sequence and saw that all of them were odd. Will it be correct to assume then that $a_{n-1}^2+2$ will be odd as well?
I thought we need to show $a_{n-2} \mid a_{n-1}^2+2$

Did you try induction?

Please, use descriptive titles. "Any hints as to how I should prove this?" says nothing about the subject of the question.

No, just from examining some terms you can't conclude that all of them will be odd.

this question looks familiar. Where did you come across it? Is it an old Putnam Q?

From oeis.org , sequence A001835 , perhaps prove that your sequence also satisfies $a_n = 4 a_{n-1}-a_{n-2}$.

https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c7h1775100p11666544

@stochs I have a question regarding the induction. Are we allowed to state something like "Let $a_n$ be an integer, and hence all $a_i,i<n$ be integers as well. We have to prove $a_{n+1}$ is an integer"

AOPS

@Gwen No, even if $a_n$ is an integer, it's not obvious why $a_{n-1}$ must be an integer. For example we could have $5 = (1^2 + 2) / ( 3/5 ). $\quad$ Note that naive induction doesn't easily work here.

https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1667604/quadratic-recurrence-relation-from-a-math-contest is similar, also https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/702952/show-that-there-is-a-unique-sequence-of-positive-integers-a-n-satisfying-a

@Gwen  there is an accessible method by Conway and Guy, I added an answer

In Conway and Guy, The Book of Numbers, especially pages 86, 87, we are shown a method "number walls"  that demonstrate   when a sequence is a "bootstrapping"  sequence  $x_n = a_1 x_{n-1}  + a_2 x_{n-2} + \cdots a_d x_{n-d}$  or linear recurrence. It also shows the value of $d$
The top row is all $1.$  The next row is the sequence being investigated.
To draw in another row, the following diagram, with $X$  neighbors $N, W, E, S $ for North, West, East, South,
is required to obey
$$ \huge X^2 = NS + EW  $$
$$
 \left( 
\begin{array}{ccc} 
 & N & \\ 
W & X & E\\
 & S & 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$
$$  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc     \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc $$
Here is the diagram for a few terms of your sequence. The confirmation is that we have degree $2,$  that is
$$   a_n = B a_{n-1}  + C a_{n-2}.$$
$$
 \left( 
\begin{array}{ccccccc} 
1 & 1   & 1 & 1  & 1 & 1  & 1 \\ 
1 & 1 & 3 & 11 & 41 & 153 & 571\\
 & -2 & -2 & -2 & -2 & -2 & \\ 
& & 0 & 0 & 0 & &
\end{array}
\right) 
$$
What does the rule
$  X^2 = NS + EW  $
mean when $W = a_{n-2}, X = a_{n-1}, E = a_n, $ finally all $N = 1$  but , it turns out, $S = -2 \; ? \; \; $  It simply says $a_{n-1}^2 = -2 + a_n a_{n-2} \;. \;$  This is precisely the original definition of your sequence.  Put another way:  by putting a first row of all $1,$
then making a third row of all constants, forces a legal second row that obeys the NSEW  rule to obey a second order linear recurrence.
Alright,
$$   a_n = B a_{n-1}  + C a_{n-2}.$$
$$ 3 = B \cdot 1 + C \cdot 1.$$
$$ 11  = B \cdot 3 + C \cdot 1$$
So $B+C = 3, 3B+C = 11.$   Subtract for $2B = 8, B = 4,$  finally $C = -1.$
We now know  $$  a_{n }  = 4 a_{n-1} - a_{n-2}$$  and calculate
$$ 1, 1, 3, 11, 41, 153, 571, 2131, 7953, 29681,..   $$


How to invent the original problem?  I have changed the $-2$ to $-47$  and started over with $1,1$
$$
\small \left( 
\begin{array}{ccccccc} 
1 & 1   & 1 & 1  & 1 & 1  & 1 \\ 
1 & 1 & 48 & 115151 & 281889551 & 690071032848 & 1689307142632801    \\
 & -47 & -47 & -47 & -47 & -47 & \\ 
& & 0 & 0 & 0 & &
\end{array}
\right) 
$$
So far  $48 = B+C$  and $115151 = 48 B + C.$  So $B = 2449$ and $C = -2401.$  This one has
$$ a_n = 2449 a_{n-1} - 2401 a_{n-2}  $$

The question is about a sequence with a quadratic recurrence
$$ a_n = \frac{a_{n-1}^2+ 2}{a_{n-2}}. \tag1 $$
Note that $\,a_na_{n-2}\approx a_{n-1}^2\,$ which is exponential
growth. Guess that it satisfies a linear recurrence
$$ a_n = p\,a_{n-1} - q\,a_{n-2}. \tag2 $$
Verify the algebraic identity
$$ (a_n a_{n-2}\!-\!a_{n-1}^2)\!-\!(a_{n-1}a_{n-3}\!-\!a_{n-2}^2)\!=\!
(1\!-\!q)(a_{n-2}^2\!-\!p\,a_{n-2}a_{n-3}\!+\!q\,a_{n-3}^2). \tag3 $$
We are given that $\,a_1 = a_2 = 1\,$ and the recurrence in
equation $(1)$ implies that $\,a_3 = 3, a_4 = 11.\,$ Assuming the recurrence in equation $(2)$ implies that $\,p = 4, q = 1.\,$
Substitute $\,q = 1\,$ in equation $(3)$ to get
$$ (a_n a_{n-2}-a_{n-1}^2) = (a_{n-1}a_{n-3}-a_{n-2}^2). \tag4 $$
Now assuming the sequence satisfies the recurrence in equation $(2)$,
then this implies, by induction, that
$$ a_n a_{n-2}-a_{n-1}^2 = a_3a_1 - a_2^2 = 2. \tag5 $$
This implies that the sequence also satisfies the recurrence in
equation $(1)$. The linear recurrence with given initial values and
$\,p = 3, q = 1\,$ implies, by induction, that it is an integer sequence.
